# Error in graph.data.frame, duplicate vertex names, how to deal with this error

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to use `igraph` for an attribute-ordered network, following a tutorial.

There are 2 lists, one (Edgelist_19) with the columns: `id1, id2, win, rank.diff`
The other list (Dominance_matrix) has the following columns: `ID, DS, normDS, Site, ranked`

This is how Dominance matrix looks:

| ID | DS | normDS | Site | ranked |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "01103F641B | 5.46930014 | 3.0938600 | ""05.2301.0"" | 5 |
| "01103F8A09 | 0.12683983 | 2.0253680 | ""05.2301.0"" | 4 |
| "01103FDEBC | -0.52922078 | 1.8941558 | ""05.2301.0"" | 3 |
| "01103F9B5A | -1.01388889 | 1.7972222 | ""05.2301.0"" | 2 |

Edit:I removed the quotes from the data to see if that caused an issue, but that did not help.

This is how the Edgelist_19 data looks like:

| id1 | id2 | win | rank.diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 011016A3EE | 01103FE406 | 3 | -3 |
| 011016A3EE | 011016C31C | 1 | -1 |
| 011016A3EE | 3B00189135 | 1 | -2 |

I'm getting the error: Error in graph.data.frame, duplicate vertex names

when I try the following code:

`library(igraph)`

`atnet<-graph.data.frame(Edgelist_19, directed = TRUE, vertices = Dominance_matrix)`

I don't know how to find these duplicate vertex names, all the column titles are different, so are the duplicates in the data then? I don't know how to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you supply some data to work with?

Comment: I edited the question with an example of what the data looks like, unfortunately I can't share more of the data.

Comment: please use `dput()` to share what data you can.  But realise that your posing a question whose answer will require detailed examination of your data.  If you can't share, that's going to make life difficult for those who try to help you.

Comment: please check: any(duplicated(Dominance_Matrix$ID)) if true check which(..)

Comment: I did find 2 values true, should those be removed from the database? @user12256545
I have also looked into dput(), but I haven't used it before and I don't know how it works :(

Comment: yes check them and remove /change the duplicates they propably cause the error

Comment: I found the duplicate values and changed them, now it does work! Thanks